# check each row and column in dataframe and replace value with user define function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'0':["qwa-abc","abd-xyz","abt-Rac","xyz-0vc"],'1':['axc-0aa',"abd-xyz","abt-Rac","xyz-1avc"],
                '3':['abc-aaa',"NaN","abt-9ac","xyz-9vc"]})
```

I have this DataFrame, I want to check each row and each column for a specific value. for example index 0
there are 4 values "qwa-abc","abd-xyz","abt-Rac","xyz-0avc".

for every value I want  to check if xxx-**any number**xx.

example:

qua-abc has **a** at the position 4, so do nothing. when it reach to xyz-**0**ac there is number 0 at position 4. hence it should run user define function to replace whole value(xyz-0vc) to whatever the user define function get.

NOTE: I tried running str.replace but it only supports specific user define string. here user function will connect to different system and get a string. hence it's not **predefine**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change all the cells in your Dataframe you need to use `pd.apply` over the row axis, so your custom function needs to take a `pd.Series` as one of the parameters. In this example row is the series.

This generator function iterates over each cell in the row, checks if the character at index 4 is numeric. If true returns the value to replace string with, otherwise it will return the value of the cell itself.

```
def replace_value(row, value):
    for cell in row:
        if pd.notna(cell) and cell[4].isnumeric():
            yield value
        else:
            yield cell

df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(replace_value(x, 'myvalue')), axis=1)
```

You then apply your custom function row wise, (`axis=1`) and wrap it in a lambda so you can pass additional arguments (`value` in this case) and then call `pd.Series` on the `iterator` returned by the function.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @NomadMonad Thanks for the answer, but I am getting out of index error.
 
<ipython-input-9-37d15dd0ccd5> in replace_value(row, value)
      1 def replace_value(row, value):
      2     for cell in row:
----> 3         if pd.notna(cell) and cell[4].isnumeric():
      4             yield value
      5         else:

IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: That might be because of that "Nan" string value which you have in the sample data

Comment: @NomadMonad used try & except method: worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate method, try this:

```
In [1200]: df.loc[df['0'].str[4].str.isdigit(), '0'] = 'myvalue'                                                                                                                                            

In [1201]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1201]: 
         0         1        3
0  qwa-abc   axc-0aa  abc-aaa
1  abd-xyz   abd-xyz      NaN
2  abt-Rac   abt-Rac  abt-9ac
3  myvalue  xyz-1avc  xyz-9vc
```

#### For doing this in all columns, do this:

```
In [1242]: def check_digit(cols,new_val): 
      ...:     for i in cols: 
      ...:         df.loc[(df[i].str[4].str.isdigit()) & (df[i].notna()), i] = new_val 
      ...:  

In [1243]: df.apply(lambda x: check_digit(df.columns, 'myval'), 1)

In [1244]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1244]: 
         0        1        3
0  qwa-abc    myval  abc-aaa
1  abd-xyz  abd-xyz      NaN
2  abt-Rac  abt-Rac    myval
3    myval    myval    myval
```

Comment: will it check for each and every value in data frame?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't 
I am getting this error:
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Well please try the exact commands. I did it again using your `df` mentioned in the question and it runs fine for me.

Comment: it works for sample df and I thank you so much for the solution :)

there are "NoneType" data value and hence it's creating a problem I believe

Comment: works like a charm. but the objective is to take that string and use it in a user define function for another string. sorry if I was not  clear.
for example it takes axc-0aa and puts in user_function() and whatever user_function returns it saves in DataFrame

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211923/discussion-between-amin-sama-and-mayank-porwal).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on @NomadMonad

string_replacer() is a function that will change value based on input value that satisfies condition

`def replace_value(row, value):
    for cell in row:
        try:
            if pd.notna(cell) and cell[4].isnumeric():
                value=string_replacer(cell)
                yield value
            else:
                yield cell
        except:
            print(row,value)
if_df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(replace_value(x,value)), axis=1)`